# draw hud elements with transparency

Tags: three.js

I would like to achieve something like on the left image where the hud is transparent and doesn't overlay on the main scene.

I put together an example in jsfiddle, full code is in the link below.

```
renderer.setViewport(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)
renderer.setScissor(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight)
renderer.enableScissorTest(true)
renderer.render(scene,camera)

renderer.setViewport(window.innerWidth-256,0,256,256)
renderer.setScissor(window.innerWidth-256,0,256,256)
renderer.enableScissorTest(true)
renderer.render(scene2,cameraOrtho)
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8e70ra6y/)

[image]

How can I make the hud transparent so it doesn't overlay the whole scene like on the left image above?

Comment: Your viewport method should work. Show your code and ask a specific question about it.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question and put together an example.

Answer (score 1):

just solved it, I added

```
renderer.autoClear = false
```

and enabled alpha